# DECLARE vs CREATE PROC Issue Oracle

Tags: database, oracle, plsql

I'm writing a stored procedure in Oracle and am having great success with my PLSQL when I run it via `DECLARE`.

However when I try to switch it over and create a stored proc (I have the permissions) I get this error: `PL/SQL: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist`

I reference the table exactly the same, through synonym, in my `DECLARE` way of doing things and it runs without issue.

Is there another permission I need for stored procs or something silly like that?

Code snippet for reference:

`select count(nbr) into v_count from cla.numericPlayer where length(nbr) != 15;`

Comment: For something like this, you should probably post a complete example that generates the error .. if you provide us only partial code, we can only give partial answer .. :)  (my suspicion: your grant to the object is via a role, so no, you really don't have PROPER permissions ...) post a full example, it'll show up much clearer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Here when you use a stored procedure make sure you have given the
>   direct object level GRANT and not by Roles.
>
> If you are trying to compile the Procedure in CLA schema then it
>   should not be any problem however if you are trying to do it on other
>   schema then you would probably need a OBJECT level GRANT. Hope this
>   helps.
>
> TRY

```
GRANT SELECT ON CLA.numericPlayer TO <SCHEMA>;
```